# drf-spectacular does not show parameters in swagger-ui if they are optional

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters, drf-spectacular

I am trying to implement some API by using GenericViewSet. I have also some FilterSet class with some custom optional fields. My issue is the generation of these custom fields in swagger-ui endpoint documentation. Generated schema just does not includes all these filtering parameters. Is there any method to solve this problem without using @extend_schema decorator with viewset actions?
Here is my FilterSet class:

```
Class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    number_field = filters.NumberFilter(required=False)
     
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('number_field', )
```

ViewSet class:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MyFilter
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/966#issuecomment-639739206

Can you check the logs and see if there's something similar to the following?

> Failed to obtain model through view's queryset due to raised exception. Prevent this either by setting "queryset = Model.objects.none()" on the view, checking for "getattr(self, "swagger_fake_view", False)" in get_queryset() or by simply using @extend_schema. (Exception: xyz)

Then handle the thrown exception in your `get_queryset`